# sql count filtering - rails way

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

Suppose I have `Posts` and posts' `Comments`. I want to filter all the `Posts` that have more than 10 comments. I began writing something like `Posts.includes(:comments).group("post.id").count("comments.id")`, to obtain a hash of `posts` and their counts, and I can extract the information from there, but I want some one-line straightforward way to do that

Sure I can use some pure `sql` syntax statements, but I want it in a pure `rails` way. Any idea ?

Comment: Given that you accepted the answer, you might want to update your question to use the correct constants (e.g. `Post`, `Comment`), after which I'll update my answer to remove the reference to this. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the models are named in the more typical singular form of `Post` and `Comment` and have the usual association relationship, then the following should work:

```
Post.joins(:comments).group('posts.id').having('count(comments.id) > 10')
```